# How to install tensorflow GPU version on VirtualBox Ubuntu OS. And host OS is windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, anaconda

I want to setup environment for deep learning using Anaconda (python 3.6). I have system having nvidia get force 1060 with windows installed on it. Now I want to have Ubuntu OS in VB. Can I install Cuda and CuDNN libraries in VB based Ubuntu OS? Any one that can help me?

Answer (score 8):

You **can not** use your GPU on **virtual box**. Because virtual box [cannot](https://superuser.com/a/1020250) pass through the host GPU.

However, you can use the windows version of python which can use the GPU on your windows machine. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) is the installation procedure for windows.

After installing `cuda`,  `cudnn` and `anaconda 3.6` I just used,

```
$ pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

That's all.