# Can I run TensorFlow GPU on an Ubuntu VM running on a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, tensorflow, virtual-machine, gpu, nvidia

I'm wondering if it'd be possible to use TensorFlow GPU running on an Ubuntu VM that's running on a Windows machine.

A search shows that this was not possible around 1.5-2 years ago as tf on ubuntu was unable to access the gpu through the VM ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273118/possible-to-virtualize-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1070-graphics-card-for-distributed-ten), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345786/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-version-on-virtualbox-ubuntu-os-and-host-os-is-wi)). According to what it says [here](https://superuser.com/questions/779070/use-nvidia-gpu-from-virtualbox/1020250#1020250), it seems like it could *technically* be a remote possibility. I was wondering if anyone has a more up-to-date experience.

Anyone know if it's possible nowadays?

Comment: Disagree with the close vote, TensorFlow is effectively still in the domain of programmers.

Comment: @yonathan: There are multiple VM hosts available for WIndows 10, although WSL2 is the default one. You link to a VirtualBox question, however. Do you have additional requirements, or is any VM host OK?

Comment: Any VM host is ok. I've been unable to find any cases in which someone was able to use TF-GPU on a VM of any kind.