# "The TensorFlow library was compiled to use FMA instructions, but these aren't available on your machine." in VirtualBox

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, virtual-machine

My tensorflow has been able to run normally in the WIN10 system, and with cuda and cudnn installed, the GPU can be used normally.
I have a whim, I want to open a tf on my own virtual machine Ubuntu, maybe I can try distributed? The result is that after finally installing tensorflow, it cannot run.
When import tensorflow, it will prompt directly
F tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:38] The TensorFlow library was compiled to use FMA instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
I don't know where the problem is...

Answer (score 2):

I am experiencing the same problem and just peeped this from another question:

[How to install tensorflow GPU version on VirtualBox Ubuntu OS. And host OS is windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345786/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-version-on-virtualbox-ubuntu-os-and-host-os-is-wi)

In short, you can't access you GPU through VirtualBox. You must do this directly from Windows/whatever machine you have.

Apologies if I didn't quote correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have found that GPU cannot be used in VirtualBox because there is no GPU in the listed devices.

Currently, we are using Ubuntu 20.04 and tensorflow 2.4. Theoretically, we should be able to use at least CPU, right? And I did use tensorflow1 in old versions of Ubuntu.